# How to create Windows Service which cannot be terminate or stop normally

Tags: .net, windows, visual-c++, antivirus, virus

I am developing a personal antivirus for windows OS. Like other popular antiviruses, I want it to not to terminate or stop from taskmanager. I am using VC++ and VB.net for developments. Other antiviruses exe's shows "Access Denied!" error message when we try to kill or terminate them.

How can I add such permissions to my antivirus exe So that it will not be terminate or kill and will show error message on terminating it?

I've searched on net but din't found anything useful regarding this.

Thanks,
Regards!

Comment: I would think something like that would get tagged as a virus or malware itself, wouldn't it?

Comment: Antiviruses uses kernel mode protection mechanism.

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorry if you've been misunderstood me. I'm asking to create Antivirus.

Comment: Thanks Xearinox, Would you like to suggest me How can i do such task programatically. Regards !

Comment: I'm still looking for any helpful reply.

Comment: @VbKiller I don't have the details but I think protected processes is something you might want to look into. Try googling it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to hook functions that could be used for terminating process & check if one tryes to terminate your process.
Second way you could hide your process, so the one who want to terminate it won't find the target for terminating.

That are simple ways that comes to my mind.

Comment: Care to provide further details on this? How would you hook to potential functions which could end the process?

Comment: Many ways were discussed there : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/create-a-unterminable-process-in-windows